# Trapezoid, ratio between two bases.

Tags: geometry

There is a point $P$ inside the isosceles trapezoid $ABCD$ such that $PA=1$, $PB=2$, $PC=3$ and $PD=4$. What is $\frac{BC}{AD}$?
[image]

My attempt:
I applied the cosine rule on those four triangles knowing that the sum of the angles at point $P$ is $360$ degrees but I ended up with too many unknowns and I stuck there.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The answer turns out to be rather nice. (Even for an arbitrary proportion of distances, the final ratio is uncomplicated.) I don't (yet) have a comparably-nice derivation of it, however.

Comment: @Blue, I've come to the same conclusion and I think the ration is 1:3 but how? :)

Comment: @Peter: My approach was to coordinatize $A=(-u,0)$, $B=(-v,h)$, $C=(v,h)$, $D=(u,0)$, and then to write relations based on the distance formula. (When the distances from $P$ to $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are, respectively, $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, then ratio $|BC|/|AD|$ turns out to be $(b^2-c^2)/(a^2-d^2)$; for the problem as given, this evaluates to $1/3$.)

Comment: @Blue, as hinted by the expression you obtained, a quick geometric solution can be found by drawing perpendicular line through P meeting the parallel sides, and applying Pythagoras in four right triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking @Blue's expression as hint, following geometric solution was found.

[image]

Draw $MN$ through $P$ perpendicular to the parallel sides as in the diagram. Then applying Pythagoras in the four right triangles, it can be shown $PD^2- PA^2 =$ $DM^2 - AM^2$ and $PC^2- PB^2 = CN^2 - BN^2$. Taking ratio,
$$\frac{PC^2- PB^2}{PD^2- PA^2} = \frac{CN+BN}{DM+AM} \cdot \frac{CN-BN}{DM-AM}=\frac{BC}{AD} \cdot \frac{CN-BN}{DM-AM}$$

Now reflect the side $AB$ in $MN$ to get $A'B'$. Clearly $A'B'CD$ is a parallelogram with equal opposite sides $B'C=A'D$. As $B'C=CN-B'N=CN-BN$, similarly, $A'D=DM-A'M=DM-AM$. Their ratio is $1$ and we have
$$\boxed{\frac{BC}{AD} = \frac{PC^2- PB^2}{PD^2- PA^2}}$$

This result holds even when say, $\triangle BPC$ is obtuse; same proof works.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hint: My drawing shows that $\angle APD=5 \angle BPC$

Also we have:

$1^2+2^2-2\times 1\times 2 \cos BPA=3^2+4^2\2\times 3\times 4 \cos CPD$

And the third relation is:

$\angle BPA+\angle CPD= 360 - 4\angle BPC$

Find angle BPC, then angle APD, these woul give you measure of BC and AD. The ratio must be $\frac 13$.